# Printing a maximum hex precision in C

Tags: c, hex

Is there any way of printing a maximum hex precision in C?

For example:

```
printf(" %x ", var);
```

gives the output as - "FFFFAB"

However, I just want the output as "AB" i.e the least 2 significant digits. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 3):

Just mask out the bits you don't want using a bitwise AND.

```
printf(" %x ", var & 0xFF);
```

Also, the 'AB' you're talking about are generally referred to as hexadecimal *digits*, not *bits*. Bits are generally used when describing binary numbers.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, that helped. Generally, all the books and web pages give how to specify minimum precision but I didn't find anything for maximum precision.

Comment: The minimum is typically the least number of digits needed to represent the number. Using a AND is just chopping off the more significant bits.

Comment: I've never seen using an AND in the printf in this way! Maybe I need to read more advance books to learn such kind of stuff. Do tell me if you know any such books for C.